# Difference between Field with type of Class name vs Field that is instantiated

Tags: c#

I am struggling to understand or see the benefits or difference over one or the other in the following code scenario.

I have a class like this which uses a field of type LoginViewModel _loginViewModel which allows me access to the LoginViewModel's classes fields and methods:

```
public partial class LoginWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly LoginViewModel _loginViewModel;

        public LoginWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;

            _loginViewModel = Resources["LoginViewModel"] as LoginViewModel;
        }

        private void okButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _loginViewModel.LoginCheck(this);
        }

    }
```

What is the difference or benefit on using the above with the following instead? They both achieve the same results.

```
public partial class LoginWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly LoginViewModel _loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();

        public LoginWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;

            _loginViewModel = Resources["LoginViewModel"] as LoginViewModel;
        }

        private void okButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _loginViewModel.LoginCheck(this);
        }

    }
```

Comment: no differences, except the second one creates additional instance of `LoginViewModel` and then never uses it as the instance is replaced in the constructor.

Comment: @extarlife I still don't understand what you mean.  In neither example will `_loginViewModel` be null after the constructor is finished (unless `Resources["LoginViewModel"]` returns null, but that doesn't seem to be what you're talking about).  The second example is just doing needless work.

Comment: My question may not be the best @KirkWoll what I am asking is why do fields that are not instantiated and are of type class I.e LoginViewModel _loginViewModel allow access to the class I.e. LoginViewModel’s methods? Which is why I asked the difference between the two examples. I was always taught unless static you had to instantiate to access another classes methods etc

Comment: @extarlife but why do you think `_loginViewModel` is not instantiated when you in fact assign it to whatever is stored at `Resources["LoginViewModel"]` at the end of your constructor?  I'm unsure what `Resources` is or why it would have your view model instance, but again, that doesn't seem to be the focus of your question?

Comment: @KirkWoll thanks I understand now the resources are the bindings to the properties in the view model. Thanks for your help